# Regex match spefcific no of chars before colon and all after?

Tags: regex

I have a feed in Yahoo Pipes and trying to match a colon, everything after the colon and a certain amount of characters before it.

Here's an example of what a normal piece of text looks like:

Charlie didn't know how to do regex **Topics: charlie, bob, learning**

What is bolded is what I would like to match, and the **Topics:** will always be the same whereas **charlie, bob, learning** will change depending on the feed item.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What regex flavor/programming language are you using?

Comment: Just regex in Yahoo Pipes. Thanks

Comment: Will be text end on "learning" or after it may be other characters?

Comment: Will "Topics: ..." text match from string one time or there may be few parts of text that match?

Answer (score 2):

```
.{6}:.*
```

Should match six characters, a colon and everything behind it.

Answer (score 2):

If you think `Topics` will always be the same then match that explicitly:

```
Topics: (.*)
```

Just matching any six characters before a colon could give you unexpected results if another key is added later.

Comment: ah I didn't know you could explicitly match. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want the `^` there? That won't match his example.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves: You're right. I assumed that it being on one line was a formatting error in the question, but I just checked the source and it does actually appear that it was supposed to be on one line.

Comment: Oops if there is any text before the word topics then this doesn't work?

Comment: Woo without the ^ it works. Sweet guys, god I love stakc overflow and especially you peeps that spare your time to help. Thanks.